Stack Overflow Developer Survey
I am unsure if I am asking this question in the correct place, but I thought I would start here. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.
I am a doctoral candidate using the Stack Overflow Developer Survey Dataset for an exploratory archival study.
I want to conduct a longitudinal study.
I want to find out if the developer survey has any variables that would identify someone so I can see if that person completed the survey for different years. This could be an email address or any kind of information I could use to identify a respondent as being a respondent in another survey.
If identifying information exists, would I be able to get it? I would obtain IRB approval, of course.

Welcome to Meta SE. Per the tag info for stack-overflow-developer-survey: "DO NOT USE THIS TAG. Most questions about the annual Stack Overflow Developer Survey should be asked on Meta Stack Overflow, not here."

related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424491/2777074 ? If you find an archived version of a user's profile, you can see in which years they participated.

Perhaps make the title more specific?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Or look at old data dumps published before the retroactive removal of the Census badge. (SE cannot control the content of old data dumps as they've already been shared on the wider Internet)

I do note that I participated in the developer survey for many years under the assumption that my answers are anonymous. I would be very curious to know if you are able to link responses between years because then I need to redefine what anonymous means.
